# Best way to handle Google Drive uploads from a back-end server

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-drive-api

I was wondering what could be the best way to handle Google Drive uploads from my web application.

In this web application the Google Drive access tokens are available with the back-end server.

I have two simple ways in my mind currently:

1. Upload directly via front-end:

The front-end app can make an authenticated request for a drive access token to my back-end. My back-end can then return the access token to the front-end. Frontend can now then directly upload the file to Google Drive.
With this approach its relatively simple, there is only single point of failure in the upload process. Also my back-end doesn't have to deal with all upload related logic. On the other hand with this approach, I have to expose the drive access token to the front-end which may not be very bad.

2. Proxying the upload via my back-end:

With this approach my front-end will first upload the file to my back-end and then my back-end going to upload the file to Google Drive. With this I don't have to expose the access token to client. But this has got a lot of disadvantages for e.g. in the upload process there are now multiple points of failure. My back-end needs to implement all that upload logic and also needs to deal large file uploads. That's why I am not so comfortable with this approach.

Is there any better / standard way of handling this thing?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest uploading files directly from the frontend. It's how it's usually done, it's more efficient and it doesn't have to involve less security. If you have any doubts about this, you can open a new question explaining the technologies you use and the purpose of the web app.